# decode/encode openssl sess.pem file

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm using `openssl sess_id -in sess.pem -noout -text` to decode the ssl session parameters in sess.pem file (which i got using sess_out) into human readable text. I wanted to know if there is a way to do the opposite i.e convert the text into sess.pem kind of format. Basically i just want to change a couple of parameters (session-id, master-key etc) inside the sess.pem file but can't seem to find the right command.

Comment: is it always the same, and why would you like to do it? [X-and-Y-Problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)

Comment: i'm trying to pentest a custom ftps server. i had a hunch that it's not properly validating the session parameters when the user tries to connect to the data port after opening a passive connection.

Comment: Related: the MySQL client has a built-in command that allows to export such `sess.pem` file with the TLS settings: `ssl_session_data_print sess.pem`

Answer (score 0):

There are no commands to manipulate or create a SSL_SESSION, but `asn1parse -genconf` can create an arbitrary ASN.1 structure in DER, which you could apply using the definition in source file `ssl/ssl_asn1.c`, and then convert to PEM with `sess_id` or just `base64` plus manual header/trailer lines.

To do it in code, the API is documented in the usual way; do `man -k SSL_SESSION` on most Unix or Unix-like. If on Windows or some other badly installed/packaged system, go to https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ and look under `PEM_*SSL_SESSION` and `SSL_SESSION_*`.

But even if some (custom) stack fails to verify saved parameters against the new hello, it basically must still use the saved parameters, so although this is at least arguably an RFC violation I don't see how it can be a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a follow-up to [@dave_thompson_085's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1073011/223409): you can use the [`PEM_read_SSL_SESSION`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PEM_read_SSL_SESSION.html) and [`PEM_write_SSL_SESSION`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PEM_write_SSL_SESSION.html) functions of the OpenSSL library to decode and re-encode the PEM file. [`SSL_SESSION_set1_master_key`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_SESSION_set1_master_key.html) will allow you to tweak the master key.